# what do they mean with "Change" in GCP daily report?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, report, settings, monitoring

***In GCP--> Monitoring --> Settings --> Email report** tab, I saved that I want to receive a daily report for utilization group, and I have received it. But the report says that the "**Change**" is "92%", and I didn't understand what they mean with "**Change**", The change for what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the email report, values in the column "% Change" display by what percentage the value in the adjacent column to the left has changed during the reported interval.

Comment: thank you so much, I have another question, for which notification channel this email is send, I Have 5 emails in the notification channel, 4 of them are project owners and one is monitoring admin, the report delivered only for the monitoring admin email, how can I send this report for all emails in the notification channel

Comment: Since this is "another question", accordingly with the SE good practices you should create a separate post for this.